# How can I smooth out the jittery display that has appeared when I installed the latest version of Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04

I downloaded the latest version yesterday and the screen display has not settled down.  Also, all of the displays seem to have been changed in size.

Comment: You mention the latest version of Ubuntu (which was the 2021-April release or 21.04) but have tagged 20.04 (three releases ago), so please clarify.   It may also help if you are more specific, or provide a link to a photo.  I assume you mean Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 or something, but it helps if you're very specific.  (20.04 was the 2020-April release, ie. a *year.month* format is used for releases, followed by 20.10 (2020-Oct), then 21.04)

Comment: Have you checked your resolution settings in the Displays setting panel? What video card? What version driver? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C video`.

Comment: I know almost nothing about Ubuntu or Linux.  I discovered that the version I have is 21.04 which i downloaded when it was recommended to me in a software update window.  The resolution settings seem to have no effect.  I do not know how to find my video card nor driver version.  I tried to download a new driver, but was not able to do so.  Also, my display is an AOC for which the company claims there is no driver.  It is not plugged into a USB port, but has a large connector/cable.

Comment: If you're using the 2021-April release of Ubuntu, please correct your question which states you're using the release from 2020-April.  The format used for releases is *year.month* showing when they were released (LTS releases can also have an upgrade level, eg. 20.04.2 states the 20.04 release with upgrade level .2 telling us it has the 20.10 kernel stack).  However if you installed 20.04, the upgrade you were offered is to 20.10 unless you've made changes and corrupted your software, as upgrades are to the next release whilst it's not EOL (20.10 isn't EOL yet) so facts provided don't add up.